# PHP/HTML - Echo an error in html div that has another echo in php?

Tags: php, html, echo

thanks for your help in advance, noob here.

So, i have this error div of a form.

```
<div><?php echo $error; ?></div>
```

I'm trying to validate an email with php, but i want its error to change depending of the language selected by the user. I have another two php files with arrays with the translated text. What i'm tryng to do is to echo the error that contains the echo for the array variable so it can be interpreted as multilingual text in the html. I know that you can't echo an echo, but i need a workaround for this. Here is the php part.

```
<?php

$error = '';

if ($_POST) {

if (filter_var($_POST['mail'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {

    $error .= '<?php echo $lang["EMAIL_INVÁLIDO"]; ?>';

};

if ($error != "") {

    $error = '<p>' . $error . '</p>';

};

};

?>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of direct echo, try assigning it to the variable and then echo the variable.

```
<?php
$error = '';
if ($_POST) {
    if (filter_var($_POST['mail'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
        $error .= $lang["EMAIL_INVÁLIDO"]; 
    };
    if ($error != "") {
        $error = '<p>' . $error . '</p>';
    };
};
?>
```

Comment: Aw lol! Haha, that worked! I tried doing it before but instead the whole array variable showed up as an error, i don't really know why it worked now, but it did. Thanks Jack, you da man.

Comment: Raul. YOu shouldn't add special characters to your array items. Like in this case, `EMAIL_INVÁLIDO`. You could do `EMAIL_INVALIDO` instead. This can prevent some headache.

Comment: I thought that wouldn't cause problems, but i'm correcting it now, thanks Phiter!

Answer (score 0):

The following should suffice:

```
if (filter_var($_POST['mail'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {

    $error .= $lang["EMAIL_INVÁLIDO"];

};
```

You do not need to put quotation marks around variables(if you do they will be treated as text, not variables) and you were already working within `<?PHP ?>` tags.

instead just echo it later in the code:

```
<?php

$error = '';
if ($_POST) {
if (filter_var($_POST['mail'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
$error .= $lang["EMAIL_INVÁLIDO"];
}
if ($error != "") {
   echo '<p>' . $error . '</p>';
}

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you say, you can´t echo an echo because PHP is server-side. You must put your echo after you now the final value of error:

```
 <?php

$error = '';

if ($_POST) {

if (filter_var($_POST['mail'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {

    $error .= '$lang["EMAIL_INVÁLIDO"]';

};

if ($error != "") {

    $error = '<p>' . $error . '</p>';

};

echo $error;
};

?>
```